# Why is KeyboardInterrupt not outputting an if-else loop?

Tags: python, keyboardinterrupt

So I have this code for a little game that I wanted to make, but the output with keyboardinterrupt isn't working. I'm kind of a noob in python, so I'm open to any suggestions to fix up my code.

Code:

```
"""
GAME
number 1-20 rapidly listing
if press Ctrl+C on 10, then win
if not, then lose and restart
"""

import time

print("Type Ctrl+C to stop")
print("If you land on 10, you win!")
time.sleep(2)
i_dict = {1: 14, 2: 13, 4: 11}
dict_num = 0
while True:

    try:
        for i in range(1, 21):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(0.07)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        i_dict[dict_num + 1] = i
        if i == 10:
            print("You Win! Nice Job!")
        else:
            print(f"You landed on {i}!")
        scores = input("Would you like to see your past scores?").lower()
        if scores == 'yes':
            for num, score in i_dict.items():
                print(f"{num}: {score}")
        restart = input("Would you like to try again? Answer with Yes or No: ").lower()
        if restart == 'yes':
            break
```

Output when I press Cntrl+C:

```
----------FINISHED----------
exit code: 2 status: 0
```

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue. I've hit both ``You landed on 1!`` and ``You Win! Nice Job!`` on separate rounds. Restarting also worked.

Comment: huh- it doesn't work for me. Maybe it's something with my editor or computer?

Comment: Note that the statement sequence of ``pass`` ``continue`` ``break`` at the end isn't exactly sensible. It should just be a single ``break`` inside the ``if`` block.

Comment: "Maybe it's something with my editor or computer?" Well, probably. That would also explain the ``----------FINISHED----------
exit code: 2 status: 0`` output.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll fix that.

Comment: What are you using for your editor and os? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Ran it from the console via ipython and python, MacOS 10.14.6. FWIW, there is nothing in the code that would suggest the behaviour is system or even version dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of using the keyboard interrupt as import I switched it to use the keyboard module, install it if you don't have it already by doing `pip install keyboard` or `pip3 install keyboard` if you are running linux you may have to run python as sudo, if you're not on linux don't worry about it.
Here's the somewhat improved code. Happy coding!

```
import keyboard
import time
print('Hit "F" to stop. ')
print("If you land on 10, you win!")
time.sleep(2)
print("Start!")
i_dict = {1: 14, 2: 13, 4: 11}
dict_num = 0
i = 0
while True:
    if i != 21:
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.07)
        i += 1
        if keyboard.is_pressed("f"):
            i_dict[dict_num + 1] = i
            if i == 10:
                print("You Win! Nice Job!")
            if i != 10:
                print(f"You landed on {i}!")
            i = 0
            restart = input("Would you like to try again? Answer with Yes or No: ")
            if restart.lower() == 'yes':
                i = 0
            elif restart.lower() == 'no':
                print("Thanks for playing")
                exit()
    if i >= 21:
        i = 0
```